# Browser-based UITestControl container

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

When writing tests using Coded UI Framework is there any benefit to start a search for a control using a container other than the browser window.

To illustrate - say I have a fairly complex html, with a lot of nesting.  Somewhere in the HTML there's something like this:

```
<nested tags (lots of them)>
    <div id='container'>
         <a lot of nested tags>
             <div id="control_I_want"></div>
             <div id="another_control_I_want"></div>
         </a lot of nested tags>
    </div>
</nested tags (lots of them)>
```

Is the search for the two controls I want to find going to be any faster if I first find 'container' and then use that as a base for searching for the two controls I want?  Or is starting with just the browser window as the base of my search going to be just as fast? I tried to code both ways but my results are inconclusive.

Code I used for testing:

```
HtmlDiv cont = new HtmlDiv();
cont.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "container");

HtmlDiv div1 = new HtmlDiv(cont);
div1.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "control_I_want");
div1.Find();

HtmlDiv div2 = new HtmlDiv(cont);
div2.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "another_control_I_want");
div2.Find();
```

and same code that uses Browser window as the parent component:

```
HtmlDiv div1 = new HtmlDiv();
div1.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "control_I_want");
div1.Find();

HtmlDiv div2 = new HtmlDiv();
div2.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "another_control_I_want");
div2.Find();
```

From your experience - is one method better than the other?  Unfortunately resources for CUIT are scarce so no amount of google helped me answer this conclusively.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trade off being made here and it depends on your application and what you think future development will look like. I think there is a minor performance difference in going the first route, but for the performance gain you loose flexibility/maintainability. If the Id of the parent container changes you will need to change it in your test as well, but with the second option your tests would continue to run normally.

I would only go the first route if performance was really important, or I was very sure the parent search properties were very unlikely to change. Even then I would probably lean towards throwing more/better hardware at the problem. I do however use the first option when I am working with controls that don't have unique search properties and the smaller container makes it easier to select the right controls.